# Can't render another component from another

Tags: reactjs, typescript, .net-core, react-router

I am having trouble rendering another component from my current component in vs code. The error message I get is..

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
>   IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode;
>   }> & ...'.   Type '{}' is not assignable to type
>   'Readonly>'.
>       Property 'match' is missing in type '{}'.

Here is my code..

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BillList } from './BillList';
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export interface BillComponentState {
    children?: React.ReactNode,
    bills: BillList
}

export class BillComponent extends React.Component<BillList>{
    public render() {
        return <div className='container-fluid'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-sm-3'>
                    <BillList />
                </div>
                <div className='col-sm-9'>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

Why can't I just render my BillList which is literally rendering a list of strings from a web api on my web server?

Disclaimer: I'm very new to React

EDIT: Here is the code in BillList.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

interface BillState {
    bills: Bill[],
    loading: boolean
}

export class BillList extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, BillState>
{
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = { bills: [], loading: true };

        fetch("api/SampleData/GetBills")
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<Bill[]>)
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    bills: data,
                    loading: false
                });
            });
    }

    public render() {

        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : BillList.renderBillsToList(this.state.bills);

        return <div className="rendered-bills">
            <h1>Bills to pay</h1>
            {contents}
        </div>
    }

    public static renderBillsToList(bills: Bill[]) {

        return <ul>
            {bills.map((bill, i) =>
                <li key={i}> {bill.name} </li>
            )}
        </ul>;
    }
}

interface Bill {
    name: string;
}
```

Here is the code in a public repo. Let me know if you need more debugging information from me.

https://github.com/ddeamaral/billTracker

Comment: try this.

export interface BillComponentState {
    children?: React.ReactNode,
    bills?: BillList
}

Comment: Try sharing minimal repro code.

Comment: changed bills: BillList to bills?: BillList still gives me the same error unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

This code sample doesn't provide enough information to tell where the error originated from. However, the React.Component first parameter accepts the components properties and you seem to be passing on a component (BillList). Also there is a BillComponentState interface defined but never used and I don't see any actual component state.

Based on this code sample I can only advise you to rename BillComponentState to BillComponentProps and pass this to the component instead of BillList.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BillList } from './BillList';
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export interface BillComponentProps {
    children?: React.ReactNode,
    bills: BillList
}

export class BillComponent extends React.Component<BillComponentProps>{
    public render() {
        return <div className='container-fluid'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-sm-3'>
                    <BillList />
                </div>
                <div className='col-sm-9'>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

But this is just guessing since we don't know what BillList looks like.

Comment: I tried to change the name and passing that to the type of React.Component and I'm still getting the same error under <BillList />

Comment: Can you try using RouteComponentProps<any> instead of RouteComponentProps<{}> in the BillList component?

Comment: I tried changing the RouteComponentProps to <any> and still have the same error.

Comment: Did you try changing all mentions of RouteComponentProps to use any? That's all I can think of at this point since the error doesn't specify mention the BillList component.

Comment: I added a link to my github repo with the project. I'm pretty certain I got all of them at least locally if not in git.